# concatenate Array Recursively

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to merge recursively arrays..

My code is:

```
var allitemorder;
var itemorder;

$('.divclass').each(function () {
      itemorder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
      allitemorder = $.merge([], itemorder);
});
```

Kindly help.

Comment: what is `sortable`? what is `merge`?

Comment: @SilentGhost:
sortable make a list into a draggable list (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable for examples)
merge(arr1, arr2) merges arr2 behind arr1. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just a slight change, like this:

```
var allitemorder = [], itemorder;

$('.divclass').each(function () {
    itemorder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    $.merge(allitemorder, itemorder);
});
```

Or the shorter:

```
var allitemorder = [];    
$('.divclass').each(function () {
    $.merge(allitemorder, $(this).sortable('toArray'));
});
```

[`$.merge(first, second)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) takes the elements from the *second* array and puts them in the *first*, so you need to pass the array you want to accumulate into as the first argument each time.

Comment: I like the shorthand version.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var array = $('.divclass').map(function () {
      return $(this).sortable('toArray');
}).get();
```

Returning an array in `.map()` automatically merges the array into the jQuery object created. Then `.get()` retrieves the final array.

Comment: This would return an array of arrays ;)

Comment: @Nick - I'm pretty sure that when `.map()` receives and array, it automatically merges it into the jQuery object array. On one occasion where I actually *wanted* an array of arrays, I found that I ended up with only one array.

Comment: Whoa you're right, that's a bug in core IMO, it shouldn't do a concat, that's an improper handling of returned Arrays specifically.  I've never tried this either but that's definitely not the expected result. +1 for this, though I'm actually *hoping* it breaks in a future version, no offense :)

Comment: @Nick - None taken. :o) I suppose it assumes it's getting an array of DOM elements or something, and therefore wants to concat. It certainly was unexpected when I came across it.

Answer (score 1):

```
allitemorder = $.merge([], itemorder);
```

Looks like you are resetting allitemorder with itemorder.
So shouldn't this be :

```
allitemorder = $.merge(allitemorder, itemorder);
```

EDIT:
as Nick states: `$.merge(allitemorder, itemorder);`
 suffices (without setting the variable allitemorder again). I would totally go with his shorthand solution.